# CarrierWave didn't save version with custom processor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have model with CarrierWave uploader:

```rb
# app/models/video.rb

class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :the_video, VideoUploader

end
```

Uploader looks like this:

```rb
# app/uploaders/video_uploader.rb

class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::FLV

  storage :file

  def move_to_cache
    true
  end

  def move_to_store
    true
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(avi mp4 mpg flv)
  end

  version :flv do
    process :put_to => 'flv'
  end

end
```

And the most interesting part - custom processor:

```rb
# lib/carrier_wave/flv.rb

require 'streamio-ffmpeg'

module CarrierWave
  module FLV
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def put_to(format)
        process :put_to => format
      end
    end

    def put_to(format = 'flv')
      directory = File.dirname(current_path)
      tmp_path  = File.join(directory, "tmpfile")

      File.rename current_path, tmp_path

      file = ::FFMPEG::Movie.new(tmp_path)
      file.transcode(current_path, {audio_codec: 'copy', video_codec: 'copy'})

      File.delete tmp_path
    end

  end
end
```

Next step I do:

```bsh
irb(main):005:0> v = Video.new
irb(main):005:0> v.the_video = File.open('/path/to/video.mp4')
irb(main):005:0> v.save
irb(main):005:0> v.the_video.size
=> 0
irb(main):005:0> v.the_video.flv.size
=> 0
```

Why CarrierWave didn't save original and flv-version?

And one more thing, when I comment version block in video_uploader.rb - everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `version` block would work as converting a video is not as easy as converting the image. You need to address different type of codecs to be used to make that conversion.

If you really want to modify/manipulate the vids look at this link It describes a gem called: **zencoder**

http://www.nickdesteffen.com/blog/video-encoding-with-uploadify-carrierwave-and-zencoder

Hope it helps.

Comment: I problem is not in converting part. For example, if we remove the contents of put_to method it will not work as expected.

Comment: Yes, in this case original file is not saved :( Version block in video.rb silently broke even original file saving.